# How does this JavaScript closure-function reuse an object without a global variable?

Tags: javascript, closures

I decided to make one step forward on trying to understand **Javascript** and read again [Javascript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0026OR2ZY).  And here comes the first doubt:

Let's say I want to avoid using the global variables because they are evil, and so I have the following:

```
var digit_name = function(n) {
 var names = ['zero','one','two','three'];
 return names[n];
}
```

D.Crockford claims that this is **slow** because everytime the function gets called, a new instantiation of `names` is done.  So, then he moves to the **closure** solution by doing this:

```
var digit_name = function () {
  var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
  return function (n) {
    return names[n];
  }
}();
```

This makes the `names` variable stored in memory and therefore it doesn't get instantiated every time we call `digit_name`.

I want to know why? When we call `digit_name`, why is the first line being "ignored"? What am I missing? What is really happening here?

I have based this example not just in the book, but on this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook&feature=related) (minute 26)

(if someone thinks of a better title, please suggest as appropriate...)

Comment: Does Crockford actually suggest this?  What page? This would make a lot more sense if there were a final `()` at the end of your code, meaning that `digit_name` gets the return value of the outer function, which is the inner function.

Comment: My mistake. Forgot to add (); at the end. Sorry guys.

Comment: _"I want to avoid using the global variables because they are evil,"_ - No they're not, any more than, say, knives are evil - it's how you use them that matters. (And even then, inappropriate use of globals is...inappropriate - not evil.). But in any case the code you start with to avoid globals immediately creates a global (`digit_name`).

Comment: @nnnnnn: I was actually citing D.Crockford, I have heard him saying that in two conferences :)

Comment: Yes, Mr Crockford seems to see everything in absolutes. I think grey areas make him nervous. (Not to say that he doesn't have plenty of good advice - the problem is figuring out which bits of advice are just his personal preferences presented as "facts".)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm sure you meant to make your second example function an immediate executing (i.e., self-invoking) function, like this:

```
var digit_name = (function () {
  var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
  return function (n) {
    return names[n];
  }
})();
```

The distinction involves scope chain with closures. Functions in JavaScript have scope in that they will look up into parent functions for variables that are not declared within the function itself.

When you declare a function inside of a function in JavaScript, that creates a closure. A closure delineates a level of scope.

In the second example, `digit_name` is set equal to a self-invoked function. That self-invoked function declares the `names` array and returns an anonymous function.

`digit_name` thus becomes:

```
function (n) {
  //'names' is available inside this function because 'names' is 
  //declared outside of this function, one level up the scope chain
  return names[n];
}
```

From your original example, you can see that `names` is declared one up level up the scope chain from the returned anonymous function (which is now `digit_name`).  When that anonymous function needs `names`, it travels up the scope chain until it finds the variable declared--in this case, `names` is found one level up the scope chain.

**Regarding efficiency:**

The second example is more efficient because `names` is only declared once--when the self-invoking function fires (i.e., var digit_name = (function() { ... })(); ). When `digit_names` is called, it will look up the scope chain until it finds `names`.

In your first example, `names` gets declared every time `digit_names` is called, so it is less efficient.

**Graphical example:**

The example you've provided from Douglas Crockford is a pretty tough example to start out with when learning how closures and scope chains work--a lot of stuff packed into a tiny amount of code. I'd recommend taking a look at a visual explanation of closures, like this one: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1482-A-Graphical-Explanation-Of-Javascript-Closures-In-A-jQuery-Context.htm

Comment: _"When you declare a function inside of a function in JavaScript, that creates a closure"_ - When you _call_ a function that was declared inside another function - each invocation has its own closure...

Comment: Calling a function declared inside of another function doesn't create a new closure. You would be re-using the closure (and each invocation would have its own private scope), but not creating a new one.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. What I meant to say was that each time you call the _containing_ function that creates a new closure. I meant that more as a clarification than a correction - you might say that the inner one isn't declared until the containing one is called, but for a newcomer to the concept they might look at the code and think everything is already declared...

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer but a clarification in case the given examples still seem confusing.

First, lets clarify. `digit_name` is not the first function you see in the code. That function is just created to return another function (yes, you can return functions just like you can return numbers or strings or objects, in fact functions are objects):

```
var digit_name = (
    function () { // <------------------- digit name is not this function

        var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

        return function (n) { // <------- digit name is really this function
            return names[n];
        }
    }
)();
```

To simplify the example and illustrate **just** the idea of closures rather than mix it up with things like self calling functions (which you might not be familiar with yet) you can re-write the code like this:

```
function digit_name_maker () {
    var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

    return function (n) {
        return names[n];
    }
}

var digit_name = digit_name_maker(); // digit_name is now a function
```

What you should note is how even though the `names` array is defined in the `digit_name_maker` function it is still available in the `digit_name` function. Basically both functions share this array. That basically is what closures are: variables shared between functions. I like to think of it as a kind of *private* global variable - it feels like globals in that all the functions have shared access to it but code outside of the closure can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the issue with the first code is that *it creates an array upon each call* and returns a value from it. It's an overhead due to the fact that you are creating an array *everytime you call*.

In the second code, it creates a closure that declares *only a single array* and returns a function that returns a value from that array. Basically, `digit_name` now carries it's own array instead of making one every call. Your function gets *from an existing array* from the closure.

---

On the other hand, closures, if not used properly can and will eat up memory. Closures are usually used to protect inner code from the outer scopes, and usually, implemented with limited access from the outside.

Objects don't get destroyed by the GC unless all references to them are "nulled". In the case of closures, if you can't get in them to kill those inner references, then the objects will not be destroyed by the GC and forever will eat memory.

Comment: Actually, when all functions involved in a closure goes out of scope all associated objects gets garbage collected. This is true for all browsers. The only exception are DOM objects that contain circular references in IE.